Laravel 11 - Executing php artisan install:api is giving "Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessStartFailedException"
I set up a new Laravel 11 project and try to install API routes by executing php artisan install:api command.
This results in the below error.
Laravel install api error
OS: Mac OS Sonoma 14.3.1 (23D60)
PHP Version: PHP 8.3.6 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2024 14:21:20) (NTS)
composer.json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "symfony/process": "^7.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^11.0.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi",
            "@php -r \"file_exists('database/database.sqlite') || touch('database/database.sqlite');\"",
            "@php artisan migrate --graceful --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}

I could not find any similar issues in the internet and trying to figure out the issue.
Executed composer require laravel/sanctum:^4.0 along.

I got this issue solved with the help of the following.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/51820
What I did was downgrade "symfony/process" to 7.0 and ran composer update
"symfony/process": "7.0.*"

Thee running php artisan install:api worked no issue.
